# Multiple file upload Connection Reset in CakePHP 2X

Tags: php, file-upload, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to upload multiple TXT file. But when I click submit button browser show

> The connection was reset".

Still now I do not add any code in controller unless function. Just view file.

```
 <?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Question', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('files.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Upload');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define an action in your controller for manage this form Question for upload your multiple text file your params array is incorrect too

> echo $this->Form->select('Model.field', $options, array('multiple' => true));